# expected integer but got "floating point number" error

Tags: tcl

I try to write a very simple program in TCL using list.

Below is the list

```
list { 1 2 3 4 5 6 1.5 7 }
```

Below is my code

```
set sum 0
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $list]} {incr i} {
    incr sum [lindex $list $i]
}

puts  $sum
```

On executing the above program I am getting the below error due to floating point value of 1.5 in the list

```
expected integer but got "1.5"
    (reading increment)
    invoked from within
"incr sum [lindex $list $i]"
```

I searched on internet and could not find anything relevant.
Please advise how do I handle the floating point value?

Answer (score 3):

While using incr command, variable must have value that can be interpreted as a an integer. See [tcl wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1476).
If variable is a non-integral real number, [incr] could not be used, but [set] could:

```
set sum 0
for {set i 0} {$i < [llength $list]} {incr i} {
    set sum [expr {$sum + [lindex $list $i]}]
}

puts  $sum
```

Comment: Strictly, it's the `+` operator in expressions that handles floating point addition, not `set` (which just writes values to variables).

Answer (score 3):

Omsai's answer should solve your problem, but a cleaner solution is to use `foreach`:

```
set sum 0
foreach n $list {
    set sum [expr {$sum + $n}]
}
puts $sum
```

Summing up a list of numeric values can also be done with the `::tcl::mathop::+` command:

```
::tcl::mathop::+ {*}$list
```

This looks more complicated that it is. The `+` command isn't available in the regular namespace, so you need to specify where it comes from (the `::tcl::mathop` namespace). The command expects to get each operand as a separate argument, so if they are in a list you need to expand that list using the `{*}` prefix.

`foreach` and the various `mathop` commands are documented here: [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [mathop](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathop.htm).

(Note: the 'Hoodiecrow' mentioned in the comments is me, I used that nick earlier.)

Comment: @glennjackman: oops, forgot to link to documentation, fixed now. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: Thanks Omsai, Glenn, Hoodiecrow. All the solutions work really well for me. Appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Tcl gives an error if you will try

```
incr a 1.5
```

you have to change the logic.

clearly you want to add all the numbers in the list. and answers are easy and many. But i will give you the shortest way:

```
set l { 1 2 3 4 5 6 1.5 7 }
set sum [expr [join $l +]]
```

**NO LOOPING REQUIRED.**